# Android 2.2 support xlargescreen layout

Tags: android

I am creating an android application which should support all screen size [normal,large,xlarge ],since I am creating application in android 2.2 which does not support xlarge screen size[like galaxy tablet 10.1].
so how can i create layout for devices which come under xlarge category?

Answer (score 1):

As far as my understanding goes, the 'xlarge' attribute was introduced in v2.3 API (9). Using the "android:xlargeScreens="true"" attribute for 'supports-screens' in Manifest file with v2.2 minSdkVersion set gives a compiler error. You'll have to use v2.3.3 API (10) to support the xlarge tag.

Which leaves to question... how to simultaneously support v2.1, v2.2, etc. while also supporting xlarge (tablets, etc.)? Two different projects? :/ Don't like that answer...

Answer (score 0):

You can put layouts for xlarge screens in "layout-xlarge" folder and drawable resources required for these xlarge layouts in "drawable-xlarge-hdpi" folder. Android OS takes layout file from here for xlarge screens automatically. Just you have to keep same layout file in "layout" for normal and large screens and same layout file in "layout-xlarge" for xlarge screens with editing as per screen size. I have already worked on this and it works perfectly for me.

Comment: I am doing the same "layout-xlarge" for large screen. BUT when I am running app in "Galexy Tab 10.1", Only **"layout-large"** layouts are showing. Is there any problem with 2.2 API ? if so then what could be the solution.

Comment: I think you need not to add "layout-large". Just keep "layout" and "layout-xlarge". For normal and large screens layout are taken from "layout" and for xlarge screens taken from "layout-xlarge".

Comment: no! its not working. now its showing normal layouts on xlarge device. Do you have any code snippet or tutorial link? Thanks in advance.